# EF Core - One to many with parent and child Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-core

**Summary**

I am trying to use Table Per Hierarchy inheritance in conjunction with a one to many relationship in a .Net Core 1.1 project. Both the Parent and child entities use inheritance. 
I have a very simple entity model. I have a one base parent entity: **Session** which has two entities which extend from it: **QuotingSession** and **BackOfficeSession**. Both of these two parent entities contain a collection of child entities (a one to many relationship). The child entities are also built using inheritance. There is a base child entity: **Policy**.  This base child entity is extended by two entities: **QuotingPolicy and BackOfficePolicy**.  When I construct either of the Parent entities and attempt to save I receive this exception:

```
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'EFTest.QuotingSession' to type 'EFTest.BackOfficeSession
```

However, when I tell entity framework to ignore one of the the child collections on either of the parents, the save works for both parent entities with no exception. For example:

```
 var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<BackOfficeSession>();
 entity.Ignore(c => c.Policies);
```

In addition if I do not configure one of the Parents (QuotingSession) at all, and just save the other Parent (BackOfficeSession), everything saves as excepted.

**Repo**

https://github.com/seantarogers/EFTest

**Details**

I am using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.1` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 1.1.1` in a `.Net core 1.1` project.

I have the following simple database schema:

[image]

My classes look like this:

**1. Session**

```
namespace EFTest
{
    public abstract class Session
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

**2. QuotingSession**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EFTest
{
    public class QuotingSession : Session
    {
        public string QuotingName { get; private set; }
        public List<QuotingPolicy> Policies { get; private set; }

        private QuotingSession()
        {
        }

        public QuotingSession(string name, List<QuotingPolicy> quotingPolicies)
        {
            QuotingName = name;
            Policies = quotingPolicies;

        }
   }
}
```

**3. BackOfficeSession**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace EFTest
{
    public class BackOfficeSession : Session
    {
        public List<BackOfficePolicy> Policies { get; private set; }
        public string BackOfficeName { get; private set; }

        private BackOfficeSession()
        {
        }

        public BackOfficeSession(string name, List<BackOfficePolicy> policies)
        {
            BackOfficeName = name;
            Policies = policies;
        }
    }
}
```

**4. Policy**

```
namespace EFTest
{
    public abstract class Policy
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int SessionId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**5. QuotingPolicy**

```
namespace EFTest
{
    public class QuotingPolicy : Policy
    {
        public string QuotingPolicyName { get; private set; }

        private QuotingPolicy()
        {

        }

        public QuotingPolicy(string name)
        {
            QuotingPolicyName = name;
        }
    }
}
```

**6. BackOfficePolicy**

```
namespace EFTest
 {
    public class BackOfficePolicy : Policy
    {
        public string BackOfficePolicyName { get; private set; }

        private BackOfficePolicy()
        {
        }

        public BackOfficePolicy(string name)
        {
           BackOfficePolicyName = name;
        }
    }
}
```

**7. EF DB Context and Fluent Configuration**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EFTest
{
    public class TestDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<QuotingSession> QuotingSessions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<BackOfficeSession> BackOfficeSessions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            ConfigureSession(modelBuilder);
            ConfigurePolicy(modelBuilder);
            ConfigureQuotingSession(modelBuilder);
            ConfigureBackOfficeSession(modelBuilder);
            ConfigureBackOfficePolicy(modelBuilder);
            ConfigureQuotingPolicy(modelBuilder);
        }

        public static void ConfigurePolicy(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Policy>();
            entity.ToTable("Policy", "dbo");
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            entity.HasDiscriminator<int>("SessionType")
                .HasValue<QuotingPolicy>(1)
                .HasValue<BackOfficePolicy>(2);
        }

        public static void ConfigureBackOfficePolicy(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<BackOfficePolicy>();
            entity.Property(x => x.BackOfficePolicyName);
        }

        public static void ConfigureQuotingPolicy(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<QuotingPolicy>();
            entity.Property(x => x.QuotingPolicyName);
        }

        public static void ConfigureSession(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Session>();
            entity.ToTable("Session", "dbo");
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            entity.HasDiscriminator<int>("SessionType")
                .HasValue<QuotingSession>(1)
                .HasValue<BackOfficeSession>(2);
        }

        public static void ConfigureBackOfficeSession(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<BackOfficeSession>();
            entity.Property(x => x.BackOfficeName);
            entity.HasMany(c => c.Policies).WithOne().HasForeignKey(c => c.SessionId);
       // entity.Ignore(c => c.Policies); uncomment this to see it working
        }

        public static void ConfigureQuotingSession(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<QuotingSession>();
            entity.Property(x => x.QuotingName);
            entity.HasMany(c => c.Policies).WithOne().HasForeignKey(c => c.SessionId);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**8. To test it**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EFTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>();
            const string conn = "Server=.\\SqlServer2014;Database=EFTest;Trusted_Connection=True"    
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(conn);
            using (var dbContext = new TestDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
            {
                var quotingPolicy = new QuotingPolicy("quotingPolicyname");
                var quotingSession = new QuotingSession("quotingSessionName", new List<QuotingPolicy> {quotingPolicy});

                dbContext.QuotingSessions.Add(quotingSession);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();  // BLOWS UP HERE!
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not set up to test this but seeing how ignore affects the outcome.  have you tried using an include to introduce the child collection to the context.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. I just added a repo with the problem in if you got a chance to look at i.

Comment: @CharlesMcIntosh I still get the same exception with the include

Comment: Is it EF Core or EF 6 issue?
I experienced same problem while my case is even simpler, because I do not have inheritance on child collection model (`Policy`)

Comment: @tutok EFCore.  I have it working in EF 6 without any problems

Comment: @jonho did you report this issue on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore)?

Comment: @tutok I am just about to do that!

Comment: @tutok -https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10446